# Can the character limit error boxes tell us how many characters we are over the limit?

Tags: feature-request, title, character-limit

I was editting a complex problem after discovering more details, and I added some details to the title. Turns out my title was too long:

[image]

Fair enough, 150 characters is a reasonable limit.

**But I had no idea *how far* over the limit I was.** I had to guess and go through trial and error - delete some words, try again, delete some more, try again - which got a little frustrating.

Normally, feedback boxes like this indicate by how much you've exceeded the limit. Could this box say, for example:

> Title cannot be longer than 150 characters. Please reduce by N characters.

Small change, but presumably quite an easy one. I've seen various other questions about having character counts while you type; that seems excessive, but info in the error box would presumably be no problem performance-wise since the character count has just been done.

Right now we can't see if we're a couple of characters over or many words over the limit.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Like I said, "I've seen various **other questions about having character counts while you type; that seems excessive**, but info in the error box would presumably be no problem performance-wise since the character count has just been done"

Comment: Two ways to achieve same goal, I still don't think each should have separate feature request. You can easily see character count in any text editor, e.g. Notepad, if that's really such a problem. (i.e. when you get "title too long" error, copy and paste it into Notepad where you can see character count, fix, and copy back.)

Comment: Well, the other one hasn't had any response in 3 years presumably because it's too much work (needs a persistent counter and UI redesign across all sites to make space for it), whereas this one has no such problems (just add a line to the popup; the count and calculation has already been done in the validation function). That's why I suggested it. The difficult solution was rejected/ignored, so here's an easier alternative.